# Edge of UV doesn't line up with edge of texture

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

The edges of my UV line up perfectly with the edges of my picture, however on the model the edges are slightly off causing the texture to repeat. The only way to prevent it is by pushing my UV's in slightly which ruins the alignment of the texture. How can I make sure they align exactly on the model?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. try to research about "texture bleeding", maybe it can help, not sure though

Comment: Seems like it was due to settings in the extension I was using.